# Find all of the paths that lead to the minimum sum

Tags: algorithm, interview-questions

"Find minimum path sum" in a 2D grid, is a very popular question which is solved by dynamic programming. But what if instead of the minimum sum value, we return all the actual paths that lead to the minimum sum path? This was an interview question which has been puzzling me.

The original problem is :

Given a m x n grid filled with non-negative numbers, find a path from top left to bottom right, which minimizes the sum of all numbers along its path.

Ex:

```
Input: grid = 
[[1,3,1]
,[1,5,1]
,[4,2,1]]

output: 7
Because the path 1 → 3 → 1 → 1 → 1 minimizes the sum.
```

But instead of 7 I want to return [1,3,1,1,1] and all other paths that lead to sum of sum (in this case there is only one path). My current solution has exponential time complexity which is not good. Does anyone has a good solution to this problem?

My current solution:

```
class Solution {
    void DFS(vector<vector<int>>& grid, vector<vector<int>>& dp, int r, int c, vector<int> path, vector<vector<int>>& result, int sum){
        int R = grid.size();
        int C = grid[0].size();        
        
        path.push_back(grid[r][c]); 
        sum += grid[r][c];
        
        if(r == R -1 && c == C -1){
            result.push_back(path);
            return;
        }
        
        int min_right = INT_MAX;
        if(c < C - 1) {
            min_right = dp[r][c + 1] + sum;
        }
        
        int min_down = INT_MAX;
        if(r < R - 1){
            min_down = dp[r + 1][c] + sum;
        }
        
        if(min_right < min_down){
            DFS(grid, dp, r, c + 1, path, result, sum);
        }
        else if(min_right > min_down){
            DFS(grid, dp, r + 1, c, path, result, sum);
        }
        else{
            DFS(grid, dp, r, c + 1, path, result, sum);
            DFS(grid, dp, r + 1, c, path, result, sum);
        }
    }
    
public:
    vector<vector<int>> minPathSum(vector<vector<int>>& grid) {
        if(grid.size() == 0){
            return 0;
        }
        
        int R = grid.size();
        int C = grid[0].size();
        
        vector<vector<int>> dp (R, vector<int>(C, 0));
        
        //O(m*n)
        for(int i = R - 1; i >= 0; i--){
            for(int j = C - 1; j >= 0; j--){
                int min_right = INT_MAX;
                if(j < C - 1){
                    min_right = dp[i][j + 1];
                }
                
                int min_down = INT_MAX;
                if(i < R - 1){
                    min_down = dp[i + 1][j];
                }
                
                int cur_min = min(min_down, min_right);
                
                if(cur_min == INT_MAX) {
                    cur_min = 0;
                }
                
                dp[i][j] = grid[i][j] + cur_min;
                
            }
        }
        
        vector<vector<int>> result;
        vector<int> path;
        int sum;
        //O(2^(m+n))
        DFS(grid, dp, 0, 0, path, result, sum);
        
        return result;
    }
};
```

Comment: You should be able to fine an O(n×m) solution, indeed.

Comment: Shouldn't this use Dijkstra's algorithm? I cannot see a DP solution for it.

Comment: @AlexisWilke, that is my question. How do you find the solution in O(n*m)?

Comment: @Athn forgive my lack of familiarity with the code - is there a specific language used? e.g. c++? If so, please [edit] and add any appropriate tags - including specific language version tags if they exist

Comment: Please tag with the language used for coding.

Comment: `My current solution has exponential time complexity`/`//O(2^(m+n))` What is this supposed to mean, starting with two obvious parameters for problem size mentioned in the problem description? Can you give an upper bound on the length of the paths to any given element? How many paths to this element are there? Does any path get considered more than once?

Comment: `I want to return [1,3,1,1,1]` You don't - consider a grid filled with 1: You want [r, r, d, d] or something else uniquely specifying paths.

Comment: `all other paths that lead to sum of sum` *all other paths with minimum sum*?

Comment: (The return value is somewhat interesting, but neither `7` nor `[1,3,1,1,1]`.)